# Welcome to Stack Exchange Pro Webmasters!

Tags: discussion, suitable-question, new-users

Welcome to Stack Exchange Pro Webmasters, a community-driven, free Q&A community for webmasters, part of the Stack Exchange network.

**What should I ask here?**

- Questions regarding the management of a site **under your control**
- Problems or questions you've encountered

**What *shouldn't* I ask here?**

- Anything not related to the management of a site
- Questions or problems about/with sites not under your control
- Questions seeking recommendations for third-party resources and tools
- Questions that will attract primarily opinion-based answers
- Questions that are too broad to be answered specifically in a few paragraphs or less

To give you a better idea of what you should and shouldn't ask, here are a few examples of *good* questions:

- [How do I find excessively suppressed redirects in MediaWiki?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65138/how-to-find-excessively-suppressed-redirects-in-mediawiki)
- [Serving WordPress menu links in only HTTPS or HTTP depending on how it's accessed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57202/serving-wordpress-menu-links-in-only-https-or-http-depending-on-how-its-accesse)

And here's a list of questions that weren't well-received by the community:

[Questions receiving downvotes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-1%20is%3Aquestion)

If you're an existing user, what would you advise to new users? Please post it as an answer below. Please post each suggestion individually (so if you have multiple suggestions, post multiple answers).

Please refer to the [general Stack Exchange introduction](http://stackexchange.com/tour) for more information about the concept of this site, and Q&A sites in general.

*Note*: This 'post' is meant for new users. I saw this on multiple other StackExchange sites and thought Pro Webmasters should have a post like this too. So here it is!

Comment: Another good initiative! Thanks for your contribution and interest in helping to improve the site.

Comment: @dan Thanks :) I hope users will continue to edit the post in order to improve it.

Comment: Are you envisioning that this gets edited into the [help center](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help) somehow?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No, actually. As long as this keeps being in 'Hot Meta Posts', this should attract new users.

Comment: We all think differently and have talents and skills as a result. Part of how we fit ourselves in life is defined by this. We can all be leaders in our own right of course and we all lead differently. It is refreshing to see one such individual expressing leadership and excellence in their participation especially in light of their age. I have absolutely no doubt that William David Edwards will be a leader in this world and will lead with excellence. It does my heart good to know such a fine young man! God Bless him.

Comment: @closetnoc +∞ Thanks.